# Javascript for mobile HTML form

Tags: javascript

I am having some problems with Javascript :(
This is an HTML form for a mobile webpage. To save space I put the names of the text fields inside the boxes. The name disappears when you focus on the box, but I am not able to make it reappear if the user didn't write anything.

Here is the Script (in head tag):

```
<script type="text/javascript"> resetDefault();{if (this.value.length==0); this.value="default";} </script>
```

Here is the HTML code:

```
<input onfocus="this.value=''" onblur="resetDefault()" name="nom" type="text" value="Nom complet" default="Nom complet"/><br><input onfocus="this.value=''" onblur="resetDefault()"name="courriel" type="text" value="Courriel" default="Courriel"/><br>
```

I keep getting a "resetDefault is not defined" error. I don't know if default is an accepted attribute for input, but I can't set it to "value" because value becomes 0 once someone has focused on the text field, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several problems with your javascript code. First, it is not syntactically correct. You should first change this code

```
 resetDefault();
 {if (this.value.length==0); 
 this.value="default";}
```

so that it has valid syntax, like this:

```
function resetDefault(){
 if(this.value.length == 0){
  this.value = "default";
 }
}
```

The second problem is that `this` refers to the global object, instead of the DOM node you want. You need to pass in a value so it knows which input to change.
Change the onblur javascript so that it passes in a parameter to the function:

```
onblur="resetDefault(this);"
```

and change the function so it accepts a parameter:

```
function resetDefault(that){
    if (that.value.length == 0){
        that.value="default";
    }
}
```

The third problem is that "default" will just change the value of the input box to the string, "default". I doubt that is what you want. Make the value match the default attribute you gave the input:

```
that.value = that.getAttribute("default");
```

Try it out on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Z2Thr/)

Comment: +1 for finding all the issues, instead of the first one like I did :-)

Answer (score 0):

The semicolon after resetDefault() in the script in the head needs to be removed - now it's a function call of a function that's not defined.

```
<script type="text/javascript">function resetDefault() { if (this.value.length==0) this.value="default";} </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the resetDefault() function like so:

```
function resetDefault() {
    // Function stuff here 
}
```